# Resources for understanding game trees?

Tags: game-theory, online-resources, algorithmic-game-theory

I am trying to make an AI to solve the popular game $2048$, and I think that the theory of game trees would help me quite a bit in this endeavor. The only issue is that most of the results I've found on google are either a bit simplistic, don't really go into enough depth to be helpful, or assume I already know a ton about the topic. Are there any resources, hopefully free, that anybody's found on the topic of game trees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you the following resources:

- [Chapter 2](http://www.umass.edu/preferen/Game%20Theory%20for%20the%20Behavioral%20Sciences/BOR%20Game%20Theory%20Basic%20Concepts.pdf) and [Chapter 3](http://www.umass.edu/preferen/Game%20Theory%20Evolving/GTE%20Game%20Theory%20Basic%20Concepts.pdf) of the comprehensive book "The Bounds of Reason: Game Theory and the Unification of the Behavioral Science" by Herbert Gintis, which deal with key concepts of game theory and game tree in a very clear manner;
- ["Game Tree Algorithms and Solution Trees"](http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48957-6_12#) by W.Pijls and A. de Bruin, a paper dedicated to game tree algorithms based upon the concept of "solution tree" (the full text should be available [here](http://repub.eur.nl/pub/763/eur-few-cs-98-02.pdf));
- ["A review of game-tree pruning"](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~tony/OldPapers/1986review.pdf), an interesting paper by T.A. Marsland focused on methods for game-tree searching and pruning, which illustrates several key concepts of game-tree analysis, such as Minimax search, $\alpha-\beta$ algorithm, aspiration and quiescence search, horizon effect, and so on;
- ["Improving game-tree search by incorporating error propagation and social orientations"](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~bswilson/papers/extended_abstract_aamas11.pdf) by B. Wilson, a well-structured thesis on the intriguing issue of the so-called game-free pathology, i.e. the study of violations of the assumptions underlying standard search algorithms, with a particular focus on potential biases in the equivalence  "deeper search = better decision" and in the assumption of player indifference to opponents'utility;
- ["2048-AI"](http://ov3y.github.io/2048-AI/), a nice AI by G. Cirillo dedicated to 2048 and for which the [code](https://github.com/ov3y/2048-AI) is also available, together with a number of interesting comments in a recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048) on Stack Overflow;
- ["An AI for 2048"](http://artent.net/2014/03/17/an-ai-for-2048-part-1/), another well-written review published on artent.net, with several interesting hints on how to create an AI for 2048.